# shinyapp out of memory even though the data size is only 500 mb

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have a shiny app that loads data reactively, and when you choose one of the datasets, it does not wait until loading is complete and then raises the error "shiny disconnected from the server".

The problem seems to be that the shiny app runs `out of memory`. However, I don't understand why this would be a problem because my total data is only 500 MB, below the 1024MB limit. How can I solve this out of memory error?

Here is the error I get:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgD20.png)

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the system's resources. Please check the following documentation, specifically sections 9.4 and 9.5.

Comment: @Bloxx which documentation?

Comment: https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/Troubleshooting.html#disconnected-from-server-messages

Comment: I've tried the solutions in that documentation but it didn't work.